# Присвоение данных в пользовательский класс

Tags: swift, парсер

Начал парсить с помощью библиотеки SwiftSoup. 
Использую пользовательский класс и массив определенный классом:

```
names: [AddClass] = []

class AddClass: NSObject {

var name500: String 
var date500: String
var ima: String
var prices: String
var sales: String
var display_price: String

init (name500: String, date500: String, ima: String, prices: String, sales: String, display_price: String) {
    self.name500 = name500
    self.date500 = date500
    self.ima = ima
    self.prices = prices
    self.sales = sales
    self.display_price = display_price
}   
}
```

Парсинг выглядит таким образом:

```
var Title: [Element] = []
var pp: Int = 1
var myURL: URL!

do {
    while pp < 6{
        myURL = URL(string: "https://..../\(pp)")
        pp += 1
        let html = try! String(contentsOf: myURL!, encoding: .utf8)
        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)

        Title += try doc.select(".item-details-title")
    }


} catch Exception.Error(let type, let message) {
    print(message)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

Вопрос такой, как можно присвоить данные в переменную класса **name500** полученные в **Title**?

**Title** в свою очередь имеет тот текст, который мне нужен:

```
Title.map{$0.text()}
```

Ранее присваивал данные другим способом парсинга и работало вроде как

```
names.map {names in
   primerTitle.map {
    names.name500 += $0.text() 
   }
}
```